# Extracting information from generated website

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using a plugin on WordPress, and it generates a [page](http://www.amavend.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=adf-preview&bannerid=21):

But the generated page is in English, and I want to generate it in German.
I already tried a few things but could not figure out which file I have to edit.
I have access to the server.

Can anyone give me tips? For example I want to change the "Add to cart" button text to German "Hinzufgen". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance all the phrases that you wish to translate in the source code, you can use a simple `String.replace` with a dictionary object.

```
var src = "<html><body><p><button>Add to cart</button></p><p><button>Add to cart</button></p></body></html>";
var toGerman = { "Add to cart": "Hinzufgen", ...};
for (var phrase in toGerman)
    src = replace(src, phrase, toGerman[phrase]);
  alert(src);

function replace(str,replaceWhat,replaceTo){
    var re = new RegExp(replaceWhat, 'g');
    return str.replace(re,replaceTo);

}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ezonhk5/)